# Declarative auth routing with Firebase

Tags: flutter

Rather than pushing the user around with `Navigator.push` when they sign in or out, I've been using a stream to listen for sign in and sign out events.

```dart
StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
  value: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
)
```

It works great for the home route as it handles logging in users immediately if they're still authed.

```dart
Consumer<FirebaseUser>(
  builder: (_, user, __) {
    final isLoggedIn = user != null;

    return MaterialApp(
      home: isLoggedIn ? HomePage() : AuthPage(),
      // ...
    );
  },
);
```

However, that's just for the home route. For example, if the user then navigates to a settings page where they click a button to sign out, there's no programmatic logging out and kicking to the auth screen again. I either have to say `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/auth', (_) => false)` or get an error about `user` being null.

This makes sense. I'm just looking for possibly another way that when they do get logged out I don't have to do any stack management myself.

I got close by adding the `builder` property to the `MaterialApp`

```dart
builder: (_, widget) {
  return isLoggedIn ? widget : AuthPage();
},
```

This successfully moved me to the auth page after I was unauthenticated but as it turns out, `widget` is actually the Navigator. And that means when I went back to `AuthPage` I couldn't call anything that relied on a parent Navigator.

Comment: wrapping your setting screen with `Consumer` as you did with first screen doesn't look good for you?I mean something like this in SettingPage.dart :  `isLoggedIn ? SettingPage() : AuthPage()`

Comment: Hi LoVe, that's one way but then I would have to do that to every route no? Say I had an about page or a verify email page, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What about this,you wrap all your screens that depend on this stream with this widget which hides from you the logic of listening to the stream and updating accordingly(you should provide the stream as you did in your question):

```
class AuthDependentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget childWidget;

  const AuthDependentWidget({Key key, @required this.childWidget})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {//you handle other cases...
          if (snapshot.currentUser() != null) return childWidget();
        } else {
          return AuthScreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And then you can use it when pushing from other pages as follows:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (ctx) => AuthDependentWidget(
              childWidget: SettingsScreen(),//or any other screen that should listen to the stream
            )));
```

Comment: Thanks LoVe, I'll for sure use this for now. I'm still curious if there's a way to do it higher up in the tree but I like your method

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to accomplish this (LoVe's great answer is still completely valid) in case anyone else steps on this issue:

You'll need to take advantage of nested navigators. The `Root` will be the inner navigator and the outer navigator is created by `MaterialApp`:

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  home: isLoggedIn ? Root() : AuthPage(),
  routes: {
    Root.routeName: (_) => Root(),
    AuthPage.routeName: (_) => AuthPage(),
  },
);
```

Your `Root` will hold the navigation for an authed user

```dart
class Root extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/root';

  @override
  _RootState createState() => _RootState();
}

class _RootState extends State<Root> {
  final _appNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        final canPop = _appNavigatorKey.currentState.canPop();

        if (canPop) {
          await _appNavigatorKey.currentState.maybePop();
        }

        return !canPop;
      },
      child: Navigator(
        initialRoute: HomePage.routeName,
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings routeSettings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
            switch (routeSettings.name) {
              case HomePage.routeName:
                return HomePage();
              case AboutPage.routeName:
                return AboutPage();
              case TermsOfUsePage.routeName:
                return TermsOfUsePage();
              case SettingsPage.routeName:
                return SettingsPage();
              case EditorPage.routeName:
                return EditorPage();
              default:
                throw 'Unknown route ${routeSettings.name}';
            }
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can unauthenticate (`FirebaseAuth.instance.signout()`) inside of the settings page (or any other page) and immediately get kicked out to the auth page without calling a `Navigator` method.

Comment: just came over  this, can you please explain more how will the auto-navigating take place? maybe provide more code please