# FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged is not triggering the stream builder when user logs out

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

My Flutter app contains few screens like settings,add product,Details page.

I am using FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged in stream builder in Main Page to decide to show Login or  HomePage based on the onAuthStateChanged change, if the user is in setting page and clicks on logout which is "FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();" , app stays on the same setting page and does not redirects to login page as mentioned in stream builder which we use in Main page as below.

```
MaterialApp(
          home: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
            builder: (ctx, snapSot) {
              if (snapSot.hasData) {
                return HomePage();
              } else
                return  LoginScreen();
            },
          ),),)
```

**Package version:**

- provider: ^4.1.2
- firebase_auth: ^0.16.1

**My expectation:**

In which ever page the user is , if he logs out he has to be taken to the login screen. As i am using
Streambuilder and i have provided the stream source as onAuthStateChanged.

**Working Scenario:**

But when the user clicks the logout when he is in Homepage screen its working as expected and the user is taken to the login page.

**Not Working Scenario:**

IF the user is in any other page its not redirecting to login page.I can see the below logs in console when sign out is clicked.

Scenario : User Navigation : Login ->HomePage -> App Drawer -> Settings Page ->Logout

```
I/flutter ( 6186): HomePage
I/flutter ( 6186): appDrawer
I/flutter ( 6186): Settings
I/flutter ( 6186): appDrawer
I/flutter ( 6186): logoutDialog
D/FirebaseAuth( 6186): Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
D/FirebaseAuth( 6186): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
```

**Work Around tried using Stream:**

**Main App file:**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<UserAccount>.value(
      value: Authservice().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
        onGenerateRoute: CustomRouter.generateRoute,
        initialRoute: homeRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserAccount>(context);
    print("user: $user");
    if (user == null)
      return LoginScreen();
    else
      return Dashboard();
  }
}
```

**Authservice File :**

```
Stream<UserAccount> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFBAccount);
  }

UserAccount _userFBAccount(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null
        ? UserAccount(
            uid: user.uid,
           )
        : null;
  }

Future<void> logout() async {
    try {
      print("logout");
      await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (error) {
      print("logout $error");
    }
  }
```

**Alert Dialogue button code**

```
FlatButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  Navigator.of(ctx).pop(); // to pop put the alert Dialogue
                  await _authservice.logout().then((value) {
                    if (Navigator.canPop(ctx)) Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                  });
                },
                child: const Text("Yes"),
                shape: Border(
                  right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ),
```

Am i missing out some logic here or is this an issue with the Firebase_auth plugin onAuthStateChanged ?

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar question I solved a while ago. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61605633/8213910)

Comment: @Nolence Thanks will try and see it.

Comment: @Nolence , was able to solve my problem with your approach mentioned in the given link by you Thank You So Much. Is there a way this could be solved in using a global navigationkey using service from Main-app till all its route navigation ? So that when user sign outs it goes to the Auth page from any page inside the app

Comment: I'm not sure as I haven't tried it but feel free to let me know if you find another solution. Having to add the willPopScope widget has always bothered me and I don't doubt there's a cleaner solution.

Comment: Do these issues solve?

Answer (score 5):

The reason why the user stays on the Settings screen when they log out is probably because your Settings screen is In a Navigator which is a child of the `MaterialApp` of your widget tree.

Since the stream listening for the `AuthStateChange` is also a child of the `MaterialApp`, the Stream and Settings page are in different widget trees.

I recommend you move your `StreamBuilder` above the `MaterialApp`.
The Settings page will also then be able to listen to AuthStateChanges.

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (ctx, snapSot) {
          return MaterialApp(
             home: snapSot.hasData ? HomePage() : LoginScreen(),
          );
)
```

This Should fix the problem

As an alternative, you can also `await` the signout event and then pop the page automatically after the user signs out.

e.g

```
await _authObject.signOut.then((value) {
  if(Navigator.canPop)
    Navigator.of(context).pop;
});
```

Comment: Tried as per the code snippet you provided to wrap MaterialApp with StreamBuilder, still the same behavior. When i try to logout from settings page its still stays in settings page.Also i a await for _authObject.signOut.

Comment: Okay after Loging out, when you press back from the setting page, does it take you to the signIn page??

Comment: Updated my post with few more code samples i am using. No it closes my app and go to android home screen. I noticed in the logs that again settings page build method is being called after i press signout.

Comment: okay remove the asyncronous task after the signOut.(The one that pops the context) and then see what it does after you signout. and press back from the settings screen

Comment: removed the pops code and tried . Still same behavior it closes my app and go to android home screen.